# Cordova OSX Platform not working

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

So this has been bugging me for quite a bit. My Cordova app works on OSX, except all the features that require Cordova plugins. The XCode log also indicates that `deviceready` has not fired.

XCode log:

`navigating to file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-feowaffvmctzslbtwdzoyypjgece/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/www/index.html
WebStoragePath is '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/com.myapp.osx', modify in config.xml.
Welcome to the My App!
ERROR: Plugin 'File' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
ERROR: Plugin 'InAppBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady`

Answer (score 0):

It seems a legit issue that hasn’t yet been solved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12448?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20cordova-osx%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC